# Getting Empty response when connecting SharePoint 2016 Excel Web Service method via SOAP client

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, excel-services, soap

We are having SharePoint 2016 farm and we try to connect the site and Excel Service via SOAP client. When we use `OpenWorkbook` for getting session ID, its working fine and the session ID is coming. With that session if we call other methods like `GetCell`, `GetRange`, `GetRangeA1`, `SetCell`, `SetRange`, `SetRangeA1` we are getting empty response.

The same methods are working fine in SharePoint 2010 sites but for 2016 sites this issue is happening.

Using Powershell commands (`New-WebServiceProxy`) also getting the same empty response error. Kindly find the exception here below and help me on this.

```
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetCell" with "6" 
         argument(s): "Server was unable to process request. ---> The request failed with an empty 
         response." ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. 
         ---> The request failed with an empty response.
            at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, 
         WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
            at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] 
         parameters)
            at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1vti_bin_ex
         celservice_asmx_WSDL.ExcelService.GetCell(String sessionId, String sheetName, Int32 row, Int32 
         column, Boolean formatted, Status[]& status)
            at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , String , Int32 , Int32 , String , 
         PSReference )
            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext 
         funcContext, Exception exception)
            at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
            at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame 
         frame)
            at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame 
         frame)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapException
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```